# AspectJ weaving into jar vs. reflective calls

Tags: java, reflection, jar, aspectj, aspectj-maven-plugin

Hei. In our Java-project we are trying to use AspectJ to clean some Exceptions from
the serverlogs. What we need is to weave advices into a jar-file such that it also triggers 
(also on reflective calls).

We are using maven and the aspectj-maven-plugin 1.7.3. When building our project the advices are being woven to all the methods, but on some of them they do not trigger.

Here is an example advice:

```
@Around("execution(* com.company.XX..*(..))")
public Object noSuchVariableExceptionWrapper(ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint) 
throws Throwable{
    try{
        return proceedingJoinPoint.proceed();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        // Code with a short log entry 
        // instead of throwing exception
        return null;
    }
}
```

We have quite a bit of code in xml-files that are parsed and run through reflection.

Any tips on how to get around this problem?

Answer (score 0):

sounds like you want to use `after throwing` instead.

Comment: No, I don't think after throwing will work. Then it's already to late to stop the exception from printing to the server-log.